# python -m build adds to version string

Tags: python, pyodide

I'm trying to build micropip from it's source [micropip](https://github.com/pyodide/micropip.git)

```
python -m build
```

works as expected, but produces a file with a version string like `0.6.1.dev1+g84a5035.d20240305`. The `.dev1+...` part causes problems downstream as `pyodide` does not accept this as a proper version.

I can't quite figure out why, where, and how that addition to the version is made during the build process and how to get rid off it. Any hint would be most welcome!

C, U.

Comment: If you're building it from source, you can always just add a version number to the `pyproject.toml` (and then remove the dynamic version indicator). But it also sounds like you should file an issue with pyodide so that the pyodide maintainers can hopefully update it to accept custom build versions.

Comment: It's because of setuptools-scm.  It means you have more commits after the rev, maybe you should checkout a specific tag first such as `v0.6.0`

Comment: Thanks. That put me on the right track, although setuptool-scm throws an error ```ERROR setuptools_scm._file_finders.git listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any```.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, as pointed out by Mike: In pyproject.toml, the version is set as a dynamic variable. This can be commented out and replaced with `version = "0.6.1"`.

Obviously, there might be a more elaborate way as suggested by wim, to checkout a specific tag. In a first test, that didn't work, but is probably the proper way.

Comment: This answer should be a comment to the original question